# Something seems wrong about this induction proof but I can't pinpoint what?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I'm a TA marking some assignments and I came across theses two induction proofs which seem like they work on a surface level. However, they also feel vaguely circular but I can't describe exactly why. I don't want to take marks off if I can't describe why this is wrong, so can anyone help me out?

First:
[image]

Second:
[image]

Comment: 1st.  The useless k(m) makes the proof clumbersome beyond consideration.  The induction needs to be on m and begin at 0.

Comment: 2nd.  Use of a = k + 1 is hocuspocus claiming the conclusion of the induction step.  The use of p seems loose for not being propertly quantified but for some reason modern teaching encourages sloopy and ambiguous quantifications.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :)

Comment: @WilliamElliot: +1 for the word 'clumbersome'.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is simply incorrect. At no point is $10^{2b+3}$ proved to be divisible by 11, all that is done is to comment on the nature of $2b+3$.

Comment: Thanks! That's a much better way for me to phrase it to the student then "this feels wrong" :P